# Solving for a monotone function - contraction operator for functions?

Tags: real-analysis, contraction-mapping

I want to solve a problem for an *increasing function* $g(x)$, for $x \in [0,1]$ and with $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$.
The solution will be solution to the following equation
$\forall x$,  $f_1(x) = f_2(g(x))$.
(with $f_1$ and $f_2$ known)

However, $f_2$ may not be invertible (it is piecewise monotone though). Thus ***for some $x$***, you have ***multiple solution*** $g(x)$, that we'll denote $(g^1(x), g^2(x), ..., g^k(x))$ (given the structure of the problem, you always have a countable number of solutions).

However, overall, there is a *unique increasing solution* $g^*()$ of $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$.
My problem is, I don't know how to ***impose the monotonicity constraint*** *when solving a system*, such that I should be able to pin down the unique solution 'directly' (I don't know if that's even possible).
Or in other words, I don't know tricks to write the system with monotonicity embedded, ***solving for the complete function $g()$, instead of solving pointwise $x$ by $x$***.

I was trying to build a ***contraction mapping operator*** (maybe it's not the way to go), but I need to embed the *monotonicity constraint* into the **contraction operator** and I don't know how to do that. (Because taken at a given $x$, our system can yield several solution and thus no contraction mapping is feasible).

PS: Just to be clear, in this particular case I know how to pin down $g()$ entirely exploiting piecewise monotonicity (and thus building piecewise invertibility). My question is really about tricks to include the monotonicity into a system (as an additional equation? constraint?), and if possible use contraction mapping with it.